# Custom sigin url not properly loading for sharepoint siite

Tags: forms-authentication, sharepoint-server

I am working on FBA authenthication for sharepoint on permises.I had created a application page for custom login and deployed on layout 15 hive.I have configured the FBA for the extended  web application.For custom sign in url I have mapped like "~/_layouts/15/sample/default.aspx". While page loading its not landing on custom url instead its loads on default url. My requirement is to land on custom url while loading my sharepoint site. But Its working fine while laoding manual like "http://mysite:2222/_layouts/15/sample/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F"

Issue is when I load   http://mysite:2222/  is not landing on custom url it loads default url.

My sample code
 sample.aspx

C# code.

using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages;

namespace Sample.Layouts.Sample
{
public partial class NewLogin : System.Web.UI.Page

{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
}
}

Regards
Gowtham

Comment: not sure is it a typo but you say you mapped to ~/_layouts/15/sample/default.aspx but you expect to load _layouts/15/sample/login.aspx those are different.

Comment: ~/_layouts/ these is relative path to make a original url for sharepoint site. I tried out with the _layouts/15/sample/login.aspx for custom sign in url its doesnt make any change.